# Prevent a post with a specific ID from being created

Tags: posts, database

Is there any way to blacklist a certain post ID, regardless of the post type, so that a post with that ID is never created?

Comment: It would be pretty hard to accomplish, since so many things are stored in the Posts table. What problem are you trying to solve? Maybe there is some way other than restricting post ID to solve the underlying issue.

Comment: The simplest solution I can think of off the top of my head would be to make manually make a post with that ID in the database and leave it as a draft.  That way no other post with that ID to could be created.  Now that may pose a problem with what you’re trying to accomplish, so if you have more details please share.

Comment: I need this for backwards-compatibility reasons. Basically, if I can prevent a certain post ID from being used, that would mean that I won't have to change something else.

Unfortunately, I can't create a draft post, as I need the post with the special ID to be non-existent.

Comment: Of course, I can change the rest of the code, but it would be less work if I can make the posts table skip over a certain ID.